# I have a data file .88 extension but don't know how to open

Tags: database, data-extraction

I have a data file .88 extension but don't know how to open it.
Please Help how to convert it to txt file

File [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3w84q3a13m4xmu/ANB06079.88?dl=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your file seems like a zip archive as suggested by the link here [Solvusoft File View Pro](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/file-extensions/file-extension-88/)

I tried renaming your file as a zip archive and it contains a file "**RAR06079.88**" inside it. It also seems password protected.

Would you know the password for it? If you do have the password, change the extension of your "**.88**" file to "**.zip**" and open it with a zipping Utility such as WinRAR or WinZIP.

Comment: No don't know the password